# How can you analogize mathematical induction to dominoes falling, if some domino can fail to topple?

Tags: foundations-of-mathematics

This analogy doesn't convince me, because what if some domino (after b, the base case) fails to topple? In real life, a domino can remain standing upright if it got placed too far apart from the previous domino — or if the previous domino didn't hit this steadfast domino with sufficient force (to topple this steady domino).

[image: Image alt text]

David Gunderson, *Handbook of Mathematical Induction* (2010), pp 4-5.

Comment: "*Any analogy will start to limp if you make it walk far enough*", that is why it is only an analogy and not an ideal model. No physical analogy can ever be equal to a mathematical abstraction. Their point is only to suggest and illustrate ideas, not to convince one of them. In real life coins are not perfectly fair and can land on a side too, that does not prevent probability textbooks from assigning probability 1/2 to heads and tails either.

Comment: Your reasoning above is based on Hume's [problem of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction), so yes in the contingent world we cannot conclude the domino will always fall (there's no such known physical law after all). The author here just uses this as a metaphorical analogy for mathematical induction proof technique which is a deductive reasoning in the idealized math world...

Comment: It is good to remain skeptical, see examples of failed attempts to use induction here https://brilliant.org/wiki/flawed-induction-proofs/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196303/fake-induction-proofs . Like with bad domino placement, it is possible to mess up proof by induction.  It is important for the analogy that all domino pairs are equal to each other, else the domino's won't all fall, or an induction may fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the intended analogy is about *ideal* dominos places in a perfect way in a perfect environment (no earthquakes), it is true that induction fails if the assumption of perfection is wrong.

As an example, consider inductive proof that x + 1 > x for integers in real world computing. Because of physical limits, in many programming environments integer overflow can happen. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

On a display with maximum 6 digits, 999999 is followed by 000000. This would be an example of one domino pair being significantly different from the other pairs. So your concern about the analogy is not wrong, but typically not relevant for mathematical proofs.